# Gulp-pug compiling all jade files instead of the one edited, saved file

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, pug

I'd like gulp-pug to not compile all jade files when I save one jade file. Instead I'd like it to compile the one jade file I edit and save.

Everything updated to their newest versions as of today.

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var newer = require('gulp-newer');
var plumber = require('gulp-plumber');
var pug = require('gulp-pug');

var paths = {
    jade: 'app/jade/**/*.jade',
    public: 'public/'
};

gulp.task('templates', function()
{
    var YOUR_LOCALS = {};

    gulp.src(paths.jade)
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(newer(paths.public))
        .pipe(pug(
            {
                locals: YOUR_LOCALS,
                pretty: '\t'
            }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.public));
});



gulp.task('watch', function()
{
    gulp.watch(paths.jade, ['templates']);
});



gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I also interested in the question. Maybe it is not optimal way, but solved the problem creating another task which compiles the exact pug file. If there is better way, I would be very glad to know!